# Updating $_SESSION variables using Ajax

Tags: php

On my main page I assign four different $_SESSION variables as follows:-

```
    <p class="p-wht space left">Working: <? echo $_SESSION['Working'] ?></p>
    <p class="p-wht green space left">Clear: <? echo $_SESSION['Clear'] ?></p>
    <p class="p-wht red space left">Busy: <? echo $_SESSION['Busy'] ?></p>
    <p class="p-wht cyan space left">STC: <? echo $_SESSION['STC'] ?></p>
```

These are set when the page loads:-

`include('status.controller.php');`

and they are set as:

```
            $_SESSION['Working'] = $status['Working'];
            $_SESSION['Clear'] = $status['Clear'];
            $_SESSION['Busy'] = $status['Busy'];
            $_SESSION['STC'] = $status['STC'];
```

They update when the page is refreshed or first loaded, but when I am trying to update them using AJAX the values don't seem to be changing.

I have tried:-

```
$(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'scripts/php/status.controller.php',
        success:function(data){
            if(data == "scripts/php/status.controller.php"){
            }else{
                alert(data);
                //location.reload();
        }
        }
    });
},4000);
});
```

but this doesn't seem to update the values. It only updates the values when the page is completely reloaded, including `location.reload();` which I don't want to use.

Any ideas?

ADDED; contents of status.controller.php file; here is the contents of this file; nathandasilva.co.uk/status.controller.txt

Comment: You have to call `session_start` in every php script working with sessions

Comment: There already is, sorry I forgot to include them

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me, what is the output of **scripts/php/status.controller.php** page. If the page will send html as output, then you should just replace the content, example:

```
<div id="content">
  <p class="p-wht space left">Working: <? echo $_SESSION['Working'] ?></p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {

   setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
         url:'scripts/php/status.controller.php',
         success:function(data) {

            $("#content").html(data);                

         }
      });
   },4000);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Does the status.controller.php include the views?

Comment: here is the contents of this file; http://nathandasilva.co.uk/status.controller.txt

Comment: As you see, your file isnt generating any output. You will need to create another ajax file, which set session and retrieve values from session and send output in json format or html and then you can just change values in the <p> tags.